# Update multiple text boxes from a single dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, forms

we have a basic ecommerce website using paypal buttons.

i want to present checkout type details to the customer depending on options they select

the choice they have is either home delivery or store collection from a dropdown box

if they select home delivery it adds $20 to total cost

a few examples:
1. where they select Store collection from a drop down list it would look like the following:

Cost:       $249.00
Delivery:   $  0.00
Total Cost: $249.00

2. where they select home delivery from a drop down list it would look like the following:

Cost:       $249.00
Delivery:   $ 20.00
Total Cost: $269.00

I was trying to play around with the following code but to no avail.

```
<html><head><title>whatever</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var textBlocks = new Array( 
'Total Cost: $269.00', 
'Total Cost: $249.00');

function changeText(form) { 
var ind = form.Checkout.selectedIndex; 
form.display.value=textBlocks[ind];  
} 

</script>


</head><body>

<form> 
<select name="Checkout" onChange="changeText(this.form);"> 
<option value="0">Home Delivery + $20.00</option> 
<option value="1">Collection in Store</option> 

</select><br> 
<textarea name="display">Total Cost: $269.00</textarea> 

</form> 

</body></html>`
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thats working fine, what's the problem? Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e4mhy93a/

Comment: thanks pablo yeah the code above works fine but i want to the dropdown box to update three fields not just one

Comment: so that when they select delivery it updates a text field called to delivery and then changes the total cost

Comment: What three fields are you talking about? You didn't mention that in you post

Comment: Cost, Delivery, Total Cost

Comment: And where are those in your code? Where are the values? etc..

Comment: thats just it, I dont know where to add it into my code, everything I try fails. Any suggestions?